# How to set up Elasticsearch for use with JHipster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a customized JHipster app with Elasticsearch. I'm running an EC2 instance on AWS (t2.medium) on CentOS7. I've deployed the app using  `docker-compose -f ./app.yml up` (have the docker container built and on my docker hub). I've installed Elasticsearch on the EC2 instance, and when I curl I get the following response.

My curl request:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/"
```

My curl response:

```
{   "name" : "node-1",   "cluster_name" : "martin-metals",   "cluster_uuid" : "8eXkzhrgQIWmL8ANGk0uUw",   "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "1fad4e1",
    "build_date" : "2019-06-18T13:16:52.517138Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"   },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search" }
```

However, when I start jHipster with the above command, I get the below error:

> martinmetals_1  | Caused by:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused) martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:136)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:70)
>   martinmetals_1  |       ... 60 common frames omitted martinmetals_1  |
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused) martinmetals_1  |       at
>   java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown
>   Source) martinmetals_1  |       at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown
>   Source) martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
>   martinmetals_1  |       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>   martinmetals_1  |       ... 71 common frames omitted martinmetals_1  |

Here is my app.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    martinmetals:
        image: msmwood/martin_metals:firsttry
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/martinmetals?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=validate
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=
            - SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=http://localhost:9200
            - SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_URIS=http://localhost-elasticsearch:9200
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: just to discard anything, it's your elasticsearch instance at `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm assuming because I can curl localhost just fine. Thanks for the response!

Comment: strange, why would you get `failed: Connection refused`. What about credentials?

Comment: I wish I knew. Just did this also:

[root@ip-172-31-80-207 centos]# netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 9200
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN

So I know it's running. I didn't set up any credentials with elastic search.